# AngularJS - Trouble Passing Values from Controller to View

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Note: I am new to Angular, but I have a general understanding of what's going on.

I have a  I want to hide when a function returns true.

```
<div ng-hide="disableElement()">
```

In my controller I have a function.

```
$scope.disableElement = function () {
    //Logic...
    return true;
}
```

Even setting this to just return true for debugging won't hide it, but `ng-hide"true"` does hide it.

Inspecting the $scope using the AngularJS Batarang shows disableElement: *null*. Is this expected?

Ideally, I want to be passing in parameters into this function, but right now I can't even get it to return a value back to the view.

Any idea why I can't pass back values?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are really in your controller in the template (`ngView` or `ngController`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-click="disableElement('HELLO')"><div>
<div ng-hide="disabled == true"></div>
```

**Function:**

```
$scope.disabled = false; 

$scope.disableElement = function (param) {

  // set to true
  $scope.disabled = true;
  console.log(param);  

}
```